# Does Christopher Pike's first officer have a name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-discovery

Rather prominently, Pike's first officer called herself "Number One" when asked in an official capacity. While she gets way more screen time in *ST:Discovery*, we never see her named. It's now apparently a gimmick of the series.

Was she ever given a name anywhere?

Comment: Hmm...Pike seems to call her "Anna" in the season finale.

Comment: It sounds like it, but what he's saying, based on the official closed captioning on the Space broadcast of the episode, is "...I'm giving you the Conn. And, uh, Admiral, do everything you can to buy Burnham more time."

Comment: I believe it’s Nuüm’bah Uan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Number_One) has to say about her name.  The upshot is there has never been a definitive canonical name assigned to her character, but she has been given a long string of possible names in various apocryphal works.

> In the Marvel *Star Trek: Early Voyages* comic book series, this character was named Lieutenant Commander Robbins. Her first name was interrupted by other dialogue, but starts with "Eure—."
>
> The novel *Vulcan's Glory*, by *Star Trek: The Original Series* writer D.C. Fontana, suggested this character's moniker was not simply a nickname or title — she was an Illyrian who was called "Number One," as the best intellect among her generation. The novels *The Children of Kings* and *Child of Two Worlds* explain that Number One does have a given name, but it's difficult to pronounce for non-Illyrians; the former suggests that she liked to be called by this name rather than her own as it enabled her to maintain a professional relationship with her captain. In the novel Captain to Captain she is referred to as "Una", however this is not her real name either.
>
> In the *Captain's Table* novel *Where Sea Meets Sky*, Number One was given the last name "Lefler" (an allusion to Robin Lefler).
>
> *Star Trek II: Biographies* gives her real name as Leigh Hudec.
>
> Peter David's *New Frontier* series of novels had a character named "Morgan Primus" who was an immortal like Flint (from *TOS*: "Requiem for Methuselah") and was the mother of Robin Lefler. It is hinted that she and Number One are the same person.
>
> ...
>
> In the *Star Trek: Discovery* novel, *Desperate Hours*, Number One had been promoted to Commander and was given the last name "Una".

Comment: Anna Una....seems kinda unwieldy! :)

Answer (score 9):

### According to the showrunner Michelle Paradise, her name is Una

From the interview with the ST:DIS co-executive producer:

> TREKCORE: Rebecca Romijn’s Number One went by ‘Commander’ or simply
> ‘Number One’ for most of her time on-screen, but it sounded like Pike
> did call her ‘Una’ one time during the finale — the character’s name
> from the Star Trek tie-in novels. It wasn’t in the captions, so can
> you confirm we heard that correctly?
>
> PARADISE: Oh yes, it was Una.

[source](http://trekcore.com/blog/2019/04/interview-star-trek-discovery-season-finale-michelle-paradise/)

#### According to Netflix, her first name is Noona (possibly an error)

This is how Captain Pike called her in [Star Trek Discovery Season 2 Finale](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Such_Sweet_Sorrow,_Part_2_(episode)).

[image]

Therefore, it seems that the name shown on Netflix is a transcript error of her real and intended name 'Una'.

Comment: That's possibly an error in the transcription. In the version broadcast on Space, the captioning has Pike saying "Report back to the Bridge, I'm giving you the Conn. And, uh, Admiral, do everything you can to buy Burnham more time."

Comment: Confirmed that it's a transcription error. I pulled up Closed Captioning on CBS All Access and [this is what it says after "conn"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0hhy.png). He doesn't pause before starting into the next sentence.

Comment: Well, I did my best :) So now we will have a continent-level canon?

Comment: *Strange New Worlds* has made this clearer now. Good answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is no short answer to this question, here is a full account of what is known within the Star Trek universe about the Illyrian-born human Starfleet officer:

The name of the Star Trek character seen in *Star Trek:Discovery* as well as *Star Trek: The Original Series* has long been controversial however in Star Trek: Short Takes episode *Q&A* her official name is displayed on her PADD confirming that her official Starfleet name is **Una** during the time when she served as Captain Pike's First Officer.

[image: LCDR Una PADD]

In this same episode however she told Spock that

> My name is Number One.

These statements are not necessarily contradictory:

**Una** is a girl's name in the English language derived from the Gaelic word for "unique." In many languages the word itself means "one":

- *Una* is the Latin feminine word for numeral "1" (literally, it means "the number 1.")
- *Una* is the Spanish feminine singular of the adjective *uno* = "One"
- *Une* is the French feminine singular of the adjective *un*, and [it is pronounced OO-na](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=fr&text=one)"
- *Una* means "One" in Irish.

Long-time Star Trek writer [Dorothy Catherine "D. C." Fontana](https://www.google.com/search?q=d.+c.+fontana&oq=d.+c.+fontana&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l3j69i60l2.7113j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) explained the origins of this name in her novel *Vulcan's Glory*, which states that this character's moniker was not simply a nickname or title – she was a product of [Illyrian genetic engineering who was called "Number One," as the best product of her batch](https://trekmovie.com/2007/08/21/classic-book-review-vulcans-glory/).

As such, the name "Number One" is a literal English translation of "Una" so both statements are technically correct.

**LCDR Una's rank and title:**

At various times onboard Enterprise she is adressed as simply "Lieutenant" rather than "Number One" or "Lieutenant Commander." This is common the in Naval forces which Star Trek rank structure emulates. In the same way that "Captain" is both a billet title, which simply means it is your job to "captain" the vessel, or the same word is also a military rank; Lieutenant is both a position title and a rank. The [military billet title 1st Lieutenant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_lieutenant#U.S._Navy_and_U.S._Coast_Guard) (abr. 1Lt) literally means that this person is the "First Officer" in succession of command, also known as the Executive Officer (XO), or "Number One," and occasionally just "Lieutenant." When the Captain addresses her as "Lieutenant" he is not using her rank, he is referring to her job. Her military rank aboard the Enterprise has always been Lieutenant Commander (LCDR) and [as the script was written](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Una) her job has always been to be the Executive Officer (*The Making of Star Trek*, pp. 22-30)

**Given Name:**

LCDR Una's given name on Illyria is impossible to pronounce according to [some novels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Una) and it has not yet been revealed within a canonical source.